# Cucumber Date Ranges Ruby

Tags: ruby, capybara

I've seen some similar questions on here regarding date ranges yet none of the solutions seem to work for me.  What i'm trying to do is have a date range of a month and confirm if today's date is within that range.  Eventually, this will be put into a case method for every month of the year as the functionality I'm testing is date specific.

I tried to convert the dates to integer to make the calculation easier (or so I thought) then use `between?` to check the date range.

This is my code:

```
today = Time.now.to_i

    month_start = Time.parse('1 Jan 2016').to_i

    month_end = Time.parse('31 Jan 2016').to_i

if today.between?(month_start,month_end)
   #do something
end
```

When having a puts on each variable, this is the output:

```
Today = 1468479863

month_start = 1451606400

month_end =  1454198400
```

As you can see, this should fail as today is not between the date range, it's far outside it. Yet, the tests are going green which would suggest my `if` statement containing the `between?` method isn't working.

Is there something blindingly obvious that I'm missing here as I can't see it.

The step in the feature is here:

```
Then(/^I can see that all results have a statement due this month$/) do
    today = Time.now.to_i

    month_start = Time.parse('1 Jan 2016').to_i

    month_end = Time.parse('31 Jan 2016').to_i

    results_table = all('table#clickable-rows tbody tr')

    if today.between?(month_start,month_end)
      results_table.each do |row|
        within(row.all('td')[3]) do
          statement_date = find('table#clickable-rows tbody tr td:nth-child(4) > span')
          expect(statement_date).to have_text '1 Aug 2016'
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you included the actual tests which pass... running the code above, `between?` works as expected, since the code inside the `if` statement is not run...

Comment: I used this month's dates and the test passed, so to confirm the test i then switched the months date to Jan to make sure that the test failed at the if statement (as it shouldn't find today's date in January) and the test still appeared to pass in the results. I've included the test in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tests pass, because if `today.between?(month_start,month_end)` return false, no expectations are run!

You might want to consider changing the if into an expectation in itself:

```
Then(/^I can see that all results have a statement due this month$/) do
    today = Time.now.to_i

    month_start = Time.parse('1 Jan 2016').to_i

    month_end = Time.parse('31 Jan 2016').to_i

    results_table = all('table#clickable-rows tbody tr')

    expect(today).to be_between(month_start,month_end)
    results_table.each do |row|
      within(row.all('td')[3]) do
        statement_date = find('table#clickable-rows tbody tr td:nth-child(4) > span')
        expect(statement_date).to have_text '1 Aug 2016'
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: I understand.  i'll use this going forward.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mis-typed this:

```
month_end = Time.parse('1 Jan 2016').to_i
```

Shouldn't it be `'31 Jan 2016'` instead?

Comment: That was a typo, it's 31 Jan in the code. Updated question

Answer (score 0):

Your whole test seems a bit jumbled - I think from the description of the step what you actually want is

```
Then(/^I can see that all results have a statement due this month$/) do
  expected_date = /\A#{Date.today.strftime('1 %b %Y')}\Z/  # rexex needed so it doesn't match 11 Jul 2016 or 21 Jul 2016

  results_table = all('table#clickable-rows tbody tr')

  results_table.each do |row|
    expect(row.find('td:nth-child(4)')).to have_text(expected_date)
  end
end
```

The results_table.each block could have also been written as

```
expect(results_table).to RSpec.all(have_selector('td:nth-child(4)', text: expected_date))
```

Comment: Turns out I was just over complicating things where I didn't need to, I've re-written the criteria for my test.